# FTP server setting with sharing directory

Tags: linux

I'm setting FTP server

Let say we create the CLASS A and CLASS B

making class A and class B not allowed to go other directories

```
chroot_local_user = yes
```

and I want to make a sharing folder between A and B

```
share/A , share/B.
```

How to make somespecific folder is allowed by some specific users like A or B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make a back-up of your `/etc/passwd` file doing below;

```
sudo cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.back
```

Locate the created user. A line should reflect as below assuming the user is `A`;

```
A:x:1001:1001:A:/home/A:/bin/sh
```

Replace `/home/A` with `/path/to/share` & save the file. Login as the user and see whether it points to `/path/to/share` by also checking for any permission issues. If permission issue persists, then add the user to the `www-data` group by doing below;

```
sudo adduser A www-data
```

and finally, restart ftp service.